# How do I set a nullable realm object

Tags: realm, realm-migration

I added migration to my project. After a lot of work I got it to work standalone. When trying to update I get the error

```
@PrimaryKey field 'id' does not support null values in the existing Realm file. Migrate using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable(), or mark the field as @Required
```

This is not for a value feature in the objects I am adding. Can anyone elaborate on this or link to documentation on how to do this? I can't find anything

This is the variable

```
   @PrimaryKey
private String id;
```

EDIT: May have solved it by doing

```
schema.get("Log").setNullable("id", true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you've updated an older code-base, then you're running into [breaking change from 0.89.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) where `@PrimaryKey` annotated fields became nullable (and `null` can be used as a primary key for 1 element).

So if you don't want your `@PrimaryKey` annotated field to be nullable, you should just add `@Required` annotation too.

Otherwise, you should add to your migration:

```
RealmObjectSchema yourClassSchema = schema.get("YourClass");
yourClassSchema.setNullable("id", true);
```